Show results for different GMM models with momentFit in R
I wonder if there is a way to show the results of different GMM model estimations, as stargazer would do, but for the momentFit package. Also, is it even possible to show estimation results from momentFit using stargazer? see code below:
# Recalculate m3 with momentFit package (s.e. are slightly different form ivreg)
m3      <- momentModel(LW~S+IQ+EXPR+TENURE+RNS+SMSA + YEAR_67 + YEAR_68 + YEAR_69 + YEAR_70 + YEAR_71 + YEAR_73, ~ S + EXPR + TENURE + RNS + SMSA + YEAR_67 + YEAR_68 +  YEAR_69 + YEAR_70 + YEAR_71 + YEAR_73 + MED + KWW + MRT + AGE, data = gril, vcov = "iid")
fit3    <- gmmFit(m3)
out3    <- tsls(m3)
s3      <- summary(out3)

# Model m3 but without homoskedasticity assumption, i.e. Two-step GMM instead of 2SLS
m3bis   <- momentModel(LW~S+IQ+EXPR+TENURE+RNS+SMSA + YEAR_67 + YEAR_68 + YEAR_69 + YEAR_70 + YEAR_71 + YEAR_73, ~ S + EXPR + TENURE + RNS + SMSA + YEAR_67 + YEAR_68 + YEAR_69 + YEAR_70 + YEAR_71 + YEAR_73 + MED + KWW + MRT + AGE, data = gril, vcov = "MDS")
fit3bis <- gmmFit(m3bis)
s3bis   <- summary(fit3bis)
s3bis

Any comment would be much appreciated it.
Best,
